# Why use "Rebase after Fetch" in TortoiseGIT?

Tags: git, tortoise-git

Why use "Rebase after Fetch" dialog when pulling in TortoiseGIT?

I have looked, and can find no documentation for this feature.

One of the few references I found implied it was equivalent to a fetch + rebase/merge.  How does this differ from a pull?

Comment: I was told that this feature cold be called "Rebase instead of Merge", because the default "pull" behavior if fetch+merge instead of fetch+rebase.  Also, "rebasing" applies to any commits (on the current branch or master) that have not yet been pushed.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in the post
[In the "Pull" dialog window, the "Launch Rebase After Fetch" options execute a "fetch" instead of "pull"](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/2735).

The answer by Sven Strickroth was :

> If you check the checkbox (ok, the naming is not perfect here), TortoiseGit executes a fetch followed by a rebase/merge when you close the dialog which is exactly which happens for a pull+rebase.

The poster's comment suggesting changing the text to one less confusing
such as "Launch Rebase After Done" has gone unanswered.

Comment: ...but if it is a pull + rebase, what are you rebasing?  Working tree changes? (I am in master)

Comment: According to the manual [Rebase](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-rebase.html) "it alters/rewrites the history of a repository".  This likely means that your request is recorded.